# CLI path is set to C:\Program Files but VS code is reading it from AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin\ and it's causing errors

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

```
"C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin\..\7.110.0-85b006b\bin\sfdx.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

can i just delete the local\sfdx folder? Because right now nothing works, it also did this two days ago where i had to reinstall java and the CLI to get it to work. Then it was working fine for a whole day and now back to not a single SFDX command working.

edit: documentation says to install it into the C:\Program Files directory which i did and it's there....but it's also installed here as well. Should i delete the appdata\local\sfdx directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

1. Uninstall sfdx-cli that you installed with windows installer (use windows programs uninstaller)
2. Install node.js : https://nodejs.org/en/download/
3. install sfdx cli with the following command

`npm install sfdx-cli -g`

Comment: now I get "bash: /c/Program Files/sfdx/bin/sfdx: No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you restart your bash , or even your computer ? sfdx in program files should not exist anymore... maybe some environment variables needs to be removed in PATH